# Should we inject a service parameter in both a child and parent service or create a method to return it from parent service

Tags: php, symfony, oop, dependency-injection

I have a few services, one, which has some variables that I need, is injected in two services, and these two are injected into another service, and I need to use a parameter from config.yml which is passed in the bottom one's constructor, into the last service.

```
vb_logger:
    class: BlotBundle\VBLogger\VBLogger
    arguments: ["@vb_members_module","@vb_posts_module"]
vb_forum_functions:
    class: BlotBundle\VBLogger\VBForumFunctions
    arguments: [%website%, %username%, %password%]
vb_members_module:
    class: BlotBundle\VBLogger\modules\Module_members
    arguments: [@vb_forum_functions]
vb_posts_module:
    class: BlotBundle\VBLogger\modules\Module_posts
    arguments: [@vb_forum_functions]
```

Here are my services. As you can see, I'm injecting **%website%, %username%, %password%** in **vb_forum_functions** and I need to access them in **vb_logger**. **vb_forum_functions** is injected in both **vb_members_module** and **vb_posts_module**. Then, I inject these two in **vb_logger**

To access my variables in **vb_logger** I need to create methods in **vb_forum_functions** that returns them, and then do something like

```
public function __construct(Module_members $module_members, Module_posts $module_posts)
{
    $this->vbff = $module_members->getVbff();

    $this->module_members = $module_members;
    $this->module_posts = $module_posts;
}
```

And in **Module_members** create a method that retrieves **vb_forum_functions** to which my variables were injected in.

```
protected $vbff;

public function __construct(VBForumFunctions $vbff) {
    $this->vbff = $vbff;
}

public function getVbff()
{
    return  $this->vbff;
}
```

Finally, in **vb_logger** I can get my variables like so:

```
 $this->password= $module_members->getVbff()->getPassword();
```

This sounds like a lot of work and bonus methods, but makes a bit more sense than to inject parameters again directly into the service, especially because they are already injected through both the two modules classes, that have **vb_forum_functions** injected into them, which already has the variables.

The alternative is

```
vb_logger:
    class: BlotBundle\VBLogger\VBLogger
    arguments: ["@vb_members_module","@vb_posts_module",%website%, %username%, %password%]
vb_forum_functions:
    class: BlotBundle\VBLogger\VBForumFunctions
    arguments: [%website%, %username%, %password%]
```

But again, the variables are already available two levels below, is it worth injecting them again?

Also, if **vb_logger** doesn't use my modules then, haven't I injected them in an improper manner? Because they also create a **vb_forum_functions** object each themselves, which will also be useless because it isn't used, in the case I use only one module. Even so, I can access this object through one of the modules, so the other doesn't have to inject it in **vb_logger**.

In short:

1. How to access a service's variables(vb_forum_functions) into a
   service(vb_logger) into which is injected two other services(the two
   modules) that each have vb_forum_functions injected into?
2. How to make it so that only the module used in **vb_logger** is
       instantiated, to avoid the other one that also creates a pointless
       **vb_forum_functions** object himself.

Comment: Consider injecting logger into your forum functions.  Also, keep in mind that, by default, forum functions will be a singleton so you are not really creating an extra one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By storing information not relevant to one service and publishing it to be used by another one you are reducing the encapsulation of those services and increasing how tightly coupled they are.

For example in the future if you changed the parent service to no longer need the injected thing then you would not be able to delete it without also changing everything that accesses it from outside.

If something is not related to the core responsibility of the service then in general it's a bad idea to add it (Single Responsibility Principle) unless the overhead of not doing so would be considerable.

In this case just inject things where you need them and keep your interfaces clean.